# this.props.getUser is not a function mapDispatchToProps - React Native, Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

As I just implemented Redux in my react native project, then I created my first reducer, action, and store, but It's not working.

**componentDidMount**

```
this.props.getUser(user());

console.log('Props: ', this.props);
```

**console.log:**

```
Props:  {screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}}
```

**Dispatcher**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return ({
        getUser: (data) => dispatch(data)
    })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(homeNav);
```

**User Function**

```
export function user () {
    return dispatch => {
        console.log(21312312);
        dispatch(request({}))
    }

    function request (user) {
        return { type: GET_USER_REQUEST, user }
    }

    function success (user) {
        return { type: GET_USER_SUCCESS, user }
    }

    function failure (error) {
        return { type: GET_USER_FAILURE, error }
    }
}
```

**Please check the screenshot below to check how homeNav is imported**

[image]

Comment: How are you importing `homeNav` component?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya Can you please check the screenshot at the end of the question?

Comment: You can try connecting it to Redux before `createStackNavigator`

Comment: I just tried placing my mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps before createStackNavigator but the connect line is still placed on last. because homeNav won't be won't be accesibble before function, It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

try changing this `getUser: (data) => dispatch(data)`

to

```
getUser: (data) => dispatch(user(data))
```

and this  `this.props.getUser(user());`

to

```
this.props.getUser(data);
```

Also need to wrap your app as below

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Route from './route';
let store = createStore(Reducers);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Route />}
        </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: also need to wrap your route and app with **Provider** as `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Route from './route';
let store = createStore(Reducers);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Route />}
        </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;` in your **App.js**

Comment: Its already wrapped and it's working in different in normal page... I think there is something wrong with createStackNavigator
`<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>`